# rtorrent won't use .rtorrent.rc

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rtorrent

I have looked around a bit on the web, and can not find a solution to this. As far as I know, I have the .rtorrent.rc file in the correct directory, but rtorrent refuses to acknowledge that it is there. The file wasn't automatically downloaded like it was supposed to, so I found one on the Internet and put it in my home directory. Below is a picture to where I have the file located. It's at the bottom. My username in this is tcochran.

This is the latest rtorrent, assuming apt-get is up to date... and I'm running Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS.

http://cloud.alternatedev.com/public.php?service=files&t=fee2a1d080ec4d2967337c6aae9a0365

So, I don't see why won't rTorrent use the file when it's in the correct location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, the wrong permissions were set on the file.

Make sure to use 755.

Comment: Did you make the file using "touch"?

Comment: You're supposed to be able to find the file on your system from when rtorrent was installed. But in the latest version it's not there for new installs. So I had to get one off the internet, but forget to set proper permissions.

Comment: Ah, okay - for future reference, a blank file will work too for anyone who doesn't feel like setting one up. - also, if you edit your question to say that rtorrent.rc wasn't DLed on install, it might be undeleted.

Comment: And BTW, the x bit doesn't need to be set, and neither does the file need to be world-readable in a proper installation.

Comment: No I didn't think it would, but 755 is my go-to permission for crap that is being a pain and it doesn't matter who can read it.